# findout when all setimeouts finish

Tags: javascript, game-physics

Checkout this demo/game i am building http://awebdeveloper.github.io/runners/

I wish to know when will all the players finish running. The Game class needs to know when all the player stop and who came first.

My question is is there a way to inform back the calling class when each of the animate finish  after all the settimeout

**Player Class**

```
function Players(ele, ptimeout)
{
    this.movePositions  = [0, 40, 80, 120],
    this.moveBy         = 5
    this.el = ele;
    this.i = 0;
    this.stop = 1;
    this.timeout = ptimeout;
    this.position = 0;

    this.animate = function(){
        /* Stop if stopped */
        playerPosition = this.el.getBoundingClientRect();
        if(this.stop || playerPosition.left > (racetrack.offsetWidth - 30)){
            this.el.style.backgroundPosition = '120px 0px';
            return ;
        }

        playerPosition = this.el.getBoundingClientRect();
        if(this.stop || playerPosition.left > (racetrack.offsetWidth - 30)){
            this.el.style.backgroundPosition = '120px 0px';
            return ;
        }

    /* Prepare Next Move */
        setTimeout(function(_this){ 
            if(_this.i < _this.movePositions.length ){
                _this.i ++;
            }
            else{
                _this.i = 0;
            }
            _this.move();
            _this.animate();
        },this.timeout,this);
    };

    this.play = function(){
        if(this.stop === 1){
            this.stop = 0;
            this.animate();
        }
    };

    this.move = function(to,positionIndex){
        this.position = to;
        this.el.style.backgroundPosition = '-'+this.movePositions[positionIndex]+'px 0px';
        this.el.style[getSupportedPropertyName('transform')] = 'translate('+to+'px)';
    }
}
```

**Game Class**

```
function Game(noOfPlayers){

    var track_tmpl      = '<div class="track"><div id="player{{ x }}" class="runner"></div></div>';
    this.noOfPlayers = noOfPlayers;

    this.players = new Array();

    for (var i = 0; i < this.noOfPlayers ; i++){
        var timeout = 120 + getRandomInt(1, (this.noOfPlayers*2));
        racetrack.appendChild(createNode(track_tmpl.replace('{{ x }}', i)));
        this.players.push(new Players(document.getElementById('player' + i), timeout));
    }



    this.play = function(){
        for (var i = 0; i < this.noOfPlayers; i++){
            this.players[i].play();
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on `Player.play` pass the `this` argument, to call from Person a function from Game.
So you will have a code like this

```
this.play = function(){
    for (var i = 0; i < this.noOfPlayers; i++){
        this.players[i].play(this);
    }
};
```

then on Player modify the code like this

```
this.play = function(game){
    if(this.stop === 1){
        this.stop = 0;
        this.animate(game);
    }
};
```

after on method animate call the game.playerFinished(Player)

on Game class write a method

```
var i = 0;
this.playerFinished = function(player) {
    console.log(player.name + " finished on position " + (i++));
}
```

where player.name a name you give on players class

Comment: of course it does, don't get confused by my example. The playerFinished will be called first by the one who finishes first. If you want ignore the other calls with some nifty checks

Comment: got it ... but is there a way other than passing around game some oop way

Comment: this is the oop way...To "speak" with an object of another class, you must have the instance and call its public method. The functional programming way is to create a global function (can be accessed from anywhere) and call that when you find the winner. If you have only one instance of the game class, then you can create a static method and you don't have to pass the instance everywhere in your logic. So you can call `Game.playerFinished(player)`